# Getting data in a PHP Array

Tags: php, object

Today I'm trying to get some datas from an PHP array but I don't know how to do this because I'm not supposed to know the name of the first key.

```
Array
(
[5bnuQsT1Y4S9yk8LRhBeLtT5PWqoAYrv2XlIGu1A] => Array
    (
        [token] => TeamSpeak3_Helper_String Object
            (
                [string:protected] => 5bnuQsT1Y4S9yk8LRhBeLtT5PWqoAYrv2XlIGu1A
                [position:protected] => 0
            )

        [token_type] => 0
        [token_id1] => 8
        [token_id2] => 0
        [token_created] => 1465668613
        [token_description] => 
    )

[df01kyz5BWtgFXDFT+70g5oSze2e3WijYEfbOSDO] => Array
    (
        [token] => TeamSpeak3_Helper_String Object
            (
                [string:protected] => df01kyz5BWtgFXDFT+70g5oSze2e3WijYEfbOSDO
                [position:protected] => 0
            )

        [token_type] => 0
        [token_id1] => 8
        [token_id2] => 0
        [token_created] => 1465668966
        [token_description] => 
    )

 )
```

I would like to get the value of each key called `[string:proected]`

I tried to vardump this : `$array[0][0]` and this : `$array[0]` but they are set to `NULL`.

When I do `vardump($array["5bnuQsT1Y4S9yk8LRhBeLtT5PWqoAYrv2XlIGu1A"]["token"]` I get only the object, but I still need to set a loop to get all the strings.

Can you help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: foreach loop might help if the structure of the array is same.

Comment: `reset( $array )`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php, to get the first element of an array, for each  `string:protected`, this should help `for each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop to grab each index out of the array like this:

```
<?php

$data = array (
    '5bnuQsT1Y4S9yk8LRhBeLtT5PWqoAYrv2XlIGu1A' => array (
        'token' => array (
            'string:protected' => '5bnuQsT1Y4S9yk8LRhBeLtT5PWqoAYrv2XlIGu1A',
            'token_type' => 0,
            'token_id1'=> 8,
            'token_id2' => 0,
            'token_created' => 1465668613,
            'token_description' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'df01kyz5BWtgFXDFT+70g5oSze2e3WijYEfbOSDO' => array (
        'token' => array (
            'string:protected' => 'df01kyz5BWtgFXDFT+70g5oSze2e3WijYEfbOSDO',
            'token_type' => 0,
            'token_id1'=> 8,
            'token_id2' => 0,
            'token_created' => 1465668966,
            'token_description' => '',
        ),
    ),
);

foreach($data as $index => $value) {
    echo $data[$index]['token']['string:protected'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks you it's work!
But can you explain to me why if I write :
`echo $data[0]['token']['string:protected'] . '<br>';` it does't work ?

Comment: because `$data[0]` dose not exist. its `$data[5bnuQsT1Y4S9yk8LRhBeLtT5PWqoAYrv2XlIGu1A]`, you can do `key($array)` to get the current key, and `reset($array)`, `next()`, `prev()`, `end()` to get value and more the pointer.  Or just use a loop.

Comment: Exactly - it's an associative array - associative arrays do not have numerical indices, but only the string index provided. Using this method is smart! :)

Comment: Okay I understand now :)
Thanks you for your help!

Comment: you could do `array_values( $array )` and then the number, but you lose the top level keys.  And that doesn't explain why you cant get the 0 index, it just makes a new array using only the values of the input array.